# Ionic pipe TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 news reader app. Property `pubDate` of class `UutinenPage` is asynchronously being assigned a value `data.items[this.id].pubDate` in uutinen.page.ts. The value should look something like `2019-02-19 04:02:00`. I need to print out this string with `toLocaleDateString()` so that the result is 19.2.2019. I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at JulkaisuaikaPipe.push../src/app/julkaisuaika.pipe.ts.JulkaisuaikaPipe.transform (julkaisuaika.pipe.ts:10)
```

uutinen.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Yle Uutiset</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="meneTakaisin()">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h1>{{ uutinen?.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ uutinen?.description }}</p>
  <p><b>{{ uutinen?.categories[0] }}</b> {{ pubDate | julkaisuaika }}</p>
  <img [src]="uutinen?.thumbnail">
  <div [innerHTML]="uutinen?.content"></div>
</ion-content>
```

uutinen.page.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { uutissyote } from './uutissyote.interface';

@Pipe({
  name: 'julkaisuaika'
})
export class JulkaisuaikaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(pubDate?: uutissyote): any {
    let pvm = new Date(pubDate.toString());
    return pvm.toLocaleDateString();
  }

}
```

julkaisuaika.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { uutissyote } from './uutissyote.interface';

@Pipe({
  name: 'julkaisuaika'
})
export class JulkaisuaikaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(pubDate?: uutissyote): any {
    let pvm = new Date(pubDate.toString());
    return pvm.toLocaleDateString();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could happen if the pubDate is null , you should add a null check before converting it to string,

```
 if(pubDate){
   let pvm = new Date(pubDate.toString());
```

Comment: Be careful though, this check will return false for empty strings as well.